# Flow Bounded Polymorphism of unknown type

Tags: flowtype

I'm trying to have a function that takes a React Component and an object as parameters with correct flow typing. So the React Component param should expect props of type `P` where `P` should have property `theme` which is of the inferred type `V`. I know `V` is an object of strings but it can still be a different type (i.e. `{ button: string }` is different from `{ checkbox: string }`). The second parameter should be of type `V`.

The point of the function is to take a React Component that requires the prop `theme` (which is just an object of strings specifically for that React Component) and use the 2nd parameter as that prop, returning a new React Component which doesn't need that `theme` prop (since it's already been given).

I have done a couple of attempts at this but still haven't gotten something working.

```
/* @flow */

type FunctionComponent<P> = (props: P) => ?React$Element<any>;
type ClassComponent<D, P, S> = Class<React$Component<D, P, S>>;
type Component<P> = FunctionComponent<P> | ClassComponent<any, P, any>;
type ThemeType = { [className: string]: string };

function mergeTheme<P: { theme: ThemeType }, V: $PropertyType<P, 'theme'>>(
    BaseComponent: Component<P>,
    injectedTheme: V
): FunctionComponent<$Diff<P, { theme: V }>> {
    const ThemedComponent = ownProps => <BaseComponent {...ownProps} theme={injectedTheme} />;
    ThemedComponent.displayName = 'Themed(' + BaseComponent.displayName + ')';
    return ThemedComponent;
}
```

The flow error

```
12:     const ThemedComponent = ownProps => <BaseComponent {...ownProps} theme={injectedTheme} />;
                                            ^ props of React element `BaseComponent`. Expected object instead of
12:     const ThemedComponent = ownProps => <BaseComponent {...ownProps} theme={injectedTheme} />;
                                                               ^ object type
12:     const ThemedComponent = ownProps => <BaseComponent {...ownProps} theme={injectedTheme} />;
                                            ^ props of React element `BaseComponent`. Expected object instead of
12:     const ThemedComponent = ownProps => <BaseComponent {...ownProps} theme={injectedTheme} />;
                                                               ^ some incompatible instantiation of `P`
```

[The Try Flow Example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgBiArgHYDGGAlnKQMJwC2OtepGAPAAoB8YAvGAAUOAE5wcAZwBcYLgEoBfAPwAlPAENKAEgCiMPIzacNpLDwDcmXATowNkyQ2at2HACIAaOd4DKfQTsHSQ51LQxtZxZSYw9vLj8eS2t8MCjXTl4BIjJKGnomaNisgB80+0d0mLdTLHjvWuTsVIAVAAtDPBabbIBvMABtcgrJADkNI1lJDFEqUgBzAF0pmbn5sABfK1QoXOpaMCNRea6Oo25ZfowzvFl2zu7Uje8ANVltLnF8UWxHvG5vABya6dQFJISoMBQsAAIQceCqxlkiLcvE8kOhcwAVnhKHgACb3SZgF6oeSyEgUfYFFzVTjadxUKBQAFgK43WQvTZJNkYqHkWjTMBEgkojDZRCkT4SSRKMAcOGSBGFDJsgB0Gsl0qkGzAIKM-F62NxGAJIt1wGS0OFN3xYrV+Kokhw9iw4yM2UBIvxQkBYAA1LD4fbHc7Xe6CIHAfJAVZraI8BhiKJSDbOnaVXSrBsgA)

[Here's a gist of my various attempts as well](https://gist.github.com/PeteJodo/4f9e87bca34ac7c0924bf674209bb7af)

My real goal is actually to have the new React Component accept an optional `theme` parameter which I would then merge with the `injectedTheme` from the above example but baby steps first.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work well for now. Not sure how *correct* it is though:

```
type FunctionComponent<P, C> = (props: P, context: C) => ?React$Element<any>;
type ClassComponent<D, P, S> = Class<React$Component<D, P, S>>;

declare function mergeTheme<P: { theme: *, [propName: any]: any }, V: $PropertyType<P, 'theme'>>(
    BaseComponent: ClassComponent<*, P, *>,
    injectedTheme: V
): FunctionComponent<$Diff<P, { theme: V }> & { theme?: $Shape<V> }, *>;

declare function mergeTheme<P: { theme: *, [propName: any]: any }, V: $PropertyType<P, 'theme'>>(
    BaseComponent: FunctionComponent<P, *>,
    injectedTheme: V
): FunctionComponent<$Diff<P, { theme: V }> & { theme?: $Shape<V> }, *>;

function mergeTheme(BaseComponent, injectedTheme) {
    const ThemedComponent = ownProps => {
        let theme = injectedTheme;
        if (ownProps && ownProps.theme) {
            const ownTheme = ownProps.theme;
            theme = Object.keys(ownTheme)
                .filter(key => !!injectedTheme[key])
                .reduce((accum, key) => {
                    accum[key] = classnames(ownTheme[key], injectedTheme[key]);
                    return accum;
                }, { ...ownTheme, ...injectedTheme });
        }
        return <BaseComponent {...ownProps} theme={theme} />;
    };
    const currName = BaseComponent.displayName || BaseComponent.name;
    ThemedComponent.displayName = `Themed(${currName})`;
    return ThemedComponent;
}
```

**Edit**

So this doesn't work completely. Take this example code:

```
type Theme = {|
    someClass: string,
    anotherClass: string
|};

type Props = { someProp: string, theme: Theme };

const SomeComponent = (props: Props) => <div className={props.theme.someClass}>{props.someProp}</div>;

const ThemedComponent = mergeTheme(SomeComponent, { someClass: 'world', anotherClass: 'idhgo' });

// The line below should work but instead flow complains
const el1 = <ThemedComponent someProp="hello" theme={{ someClass: 'hello' }} />
```

The flow error in question:

```
47: type Props = { someProp: string, theme: Theme };
                                            ^ property `anotherClass`. Property not found in
52: const el1 = <ThemedComponent someProp="hello" theme={{ someClass: 'poop' }} />
                                                         ^ object literal
```

[Here's a link to the "Try Flow"](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiCWBbADrATgF1AEoCmAhgMb6TaxqgDk2pFdA3KpjvmdCQM68A7EmiK9QVGvW59Bw0a2S4AnhiKgAYgFcBFFLAEBhGlgFEBuADwAFADSgDAPlABeUAAoM1DLwBcoW6Bk+rhEAB64fgYAlC5OAPzE5LgAJACi0EQi5hYkAkoObMqq9jz8Rhym2QAidgEAyk6uBqW8FokUyeUmZpY1-nYNBcgAJkTSjOLauvqgItgA5kQAKgAWmUTWfgDeoADanrAYAHJyfgBUALrnoAC+dgBqfslWXkR4SksqGwF0uGsidAcDjciFAYNAACE+EQuvoepEWrDKpYzrU7GcHDZQeCUAIAFZjELDVbrPz3RBRPxaHS4PSGYxw7LJKooSCQax2HZ-Umge63TGgDFsRAgUCiaC43AAWmGKF4JAARhkpaZwlKJaZQAJYFLGKNxkREPqeBNIFNaTM5osSSJNqAuf8iOc7PsvCcROcroLbg8ni9Dm9lJ9VBz6NyAUCQeDIdCkfCNOa6XHsgEMVjo7iCRQiMTHWSKVTE-pk5Zmaz2QEHTy+TcnAAye2gcNEOJPOorEgh+5OO6CoYisDiyUyuWK5Wq6UatTa3U5sYmw1mml02Zva2OtxQ3gwhnIuyZwk5m1EGJbbFgoICXj4Y-DEsuUAIAT+7yxe3n6OgDL4ZsPg-Z3N1jYT8cUgdwnxfMQ6wbCCvF4AA6ZtTw-ECL30a9H3gARjwfWDDgQ5tgNQ6Nf1cAB5BUs1weCAGsiCUXg3CfY8ohQ4jwXgyAUGgEJsDcOilDfABCIT-yJY9dgEi5WPY1D4L1TQyCINw3HIMhNDQOwBJiZwnDPWTZLUjTJPoi4H2kfghBERjmMdEylAufd8UPQCRHs6SiIM1DGFwTRsAEUAjLQTyvJ9Rt4Ii2z1jsCL4LEo9HVuKIQujG42LBHy-ICiwtx3CoentWK8O8G4m0dZwtmbUrgCGVKQsvDD1OwbB3TUVxcpLeDZV4DAeCUVrQAAH0GmNt06qyiBC29Ou63qSH6uQHwAA1vNxki2JqWrkG4oiWkLMv80Bpt3Ho2DSxAwiwPBQFGSASE0HjVwWZZHWFIo1Bw1x9PBXgaBhFo-GvbBcXmdNwVyWBuWwZoZEB3BgYEeZEBuN6vn8OCHx2X6RBfOGEdBsqeRwlHkAa-A6j++9XA8OC-EgnSnAsWUADdAhaVqKoObxEMdeDsf+mRay2LmEP5l8bgsYAWf7MmjsdO8TvMB8rRe9Y3ApkQS05UB+Zh-g-DoeAcGgYY6DsCGob13x6DWaA4DoJK2FlohoAARgfCxjvypWxa8ZwACJbbgf3CZECqscpgH6CwQ4HZuaqHEQIA)